# Magento 1.9 Invalid block type: Mage_Checkout_Block_1cart_Header

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento home page shows white screen. In var/log/exception.log, i have

```
2018-12-19T03:30:18+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Header' in /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('checkout/cart_h...', Array)
#2 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('checkout/cart_h...', 'top_cart')
#3 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('checkout/cart_h...', 'top_cart')
#4 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home|21')
#9 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home|21')
#10 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /mnt/data/sites/teamattitude.com.au/html/index.php(93): Mage::run('teamattitude', 'website')
#16 {main}
```

I have the class  Mage_Checkout_Block_1cart_Header in following 2 locations.

```
app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Header.php
includes/src/Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Header.php
```

Content of both files are identical.

app/design/frontend/mercado/default/layout/checkout.xml  have following code

```
<block type="checkout/cart_header" name="top_cart" template="checkout/cart/mini_cart_top.phtml"></block>
```

file "mini_cart_top.phtml" exists in app/design/frontend/mercado/default/template/checkout/cart/mini_cart_top.phtml

mercado is the theme site use.

Any idea how to fix this error ?

Comment: if you are using `checkout/cart_header` block for your phtml, check there is a block class `Header.php` at `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart`

Comment: Don't have any Cart/Header.php in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart folder. Here are the Header.php i have - https://pastebin.com/raw/spWh2J4B If i have to create one, how i do ?

Comment: for testing copy with same location in `core`  code pool folder

Comment: I did "cp app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Header.php app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Header.php". This stopped error in "exception.log". But site still shows "500 Internal Server Error". Nothing in logs.. where do i check ?

Comment: could you paste code of file ?